# Duplicate part of screen to external monitor

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors

I'm a teacher, and I often do some live programming on my laptop. In this setting, my laptop is in front of me, and it is duplicated to the projector behind me. A big disadvantage of this is that I can't use my laptop for notes, google, etc. I cannot use the extend function, as I always face the classroom so my back is to the projector.

What I'm looking for is a way to duplicate only a part of my main monitor to the projector (on Windows), so I can use the rest of my main monitor for other things the class does not see. For example: the top right of my laptop screen is mirorred to the projector. The rest of the screen is only visible on my laptop.

Comment: Can you not extend your screens: Screen1=Monitor/Laptop, Screen2=Projector? Then you just drag JUST the apps you want to the projector?

Comment: The correct solution to this problem is to duplicate one of the monitors and use that application as the monitor you will display.  Tthere is a keyboard shortcut to quickly connect and disconnect a projector  (WinKey + P).

Answer (score 1):

As you cant extend the desktop, and duplicating part of a screen is impractical, you can use a second monitor and duplicate that one to the projector, then you can have the two in front of you allowing you the privacy of your primary monitor

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).